# Wald Statistic univariate case

Tags: self-study, chi-squared-test, fisher-information

The Wald statistic in the univariate case

$T_w  = \dfrac{(\hat{\beta} - \beta_0)^2}{I{(\hat{\beta})}} \sim \chi^2(1)$

where $\hat{\beta}$ is the ML estimate of $\beta$ and $\beta_0$ is the null hypothesis for beta. Now what I am asking for is if someone can show me how

$I(\hat{\beta}) = Var(\hat{\beta})$

The fisher information evaluated at the ML estimate of $\beta$

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: @gung ok sorry i forgot

Answer (score 1):

$I(\hat{\beta}) \neq Var(\hat{\beta})$ in general, but it is the asymptotic variance of the MLE under certain [regularity conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood).

I'm not sure at which level of detail to answer your question.  Is that sufficient?  The proof for the asymptotic convergence of the MLE relies on quite a few fundamental concepts of probability, such as one of the Laws of Large Numbers, and is generally proven by using a Taylor series expansion of the score function, i.e. $S(\beta) = \frac{\partial log(f_{W}(\beta))}{\partial \beta}$.